# Want to add "Back" button in dspace

Tags: xml, xslt, dspace

I want to add **Previous** and **Next** button in dspace 4.2 XMLUI version.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using the following code in file **[dspace-install]/webapps/xmlui/themes/MyTheme/lib/xsl/core/page-structure.xsl**-‌​>

```html
<xsl:variable name="isHomePage" select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@qualifier='URI'][1]/no‌​de()"/> 

<xsl:if test="$isHomePage != ''"> 
  <div class="backbtndiv"> 
    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="backbtn">BACK</a> 
  </div> 
</xsl:if>
```